# Player stage error, failed to parse config file

Tags: ubuntu, shared-libraries, robotics, player-stage

I am working on my project for this purpose I am installing player and stage simulation environment in **Ubuntu 14.04** I have successfully installed everything but when I try to run this command
Mydirectory/worlds$ player simple.cfg
I am getting this error [image]

> error: Sorry, no support for shared libraries, so can't load plugins.
> error   : You should install libltdl, which is part of GNU libtool, then re-compile player.
> error   : failed to load plugin: stageplugin
> error   : failed to parse config file simple.cfg driver blocks

On the other hand when I run this command
Mydirectory/worlds$ stage simple.world
and this command running successfully [image]

Solutions I have tried so far

1. installation of player stage on ubuntu 12.04 but same error
2. installation on 14.04 and 16.04 but same error
3. forum support but they are saying install player stage 3-4 times then it may solve the issue.
4. Adding path to the bshrc. file but same error
5. Using synaptic package installer try to find libltdl-ltdl-1 but nothing found
6. found one patch file for stage but still same error

Anyone can help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand (from the top of my head) you can install player/stage in two ways:

1. As two separate programs
2. Stage as a plugin of player

It seems what you have is option 1. If both work and you can simulate your programs I don't see the need to keep installing.

Re ltdl, I installed player/stage some years ago in Ubuntu 12.04 (or 14.04) and installed libltdl-dev package. Hope this helps.

Regards